Как реализовать поиск и выбор категории?
Есть компонент input и компонент select с категориями user и repo.
При первом рендере страницы ,у нас отобразятся данные с категорией user и будет компонент для отображения этих карточек, в которые передается имя пользователя и сколько всего репозиториев. Данные берутся с github api. При выборе repo у нас отобразятся уже новые карточки с названием репозиториев и сколько звезд присвоено.
Поиск должен происходить так, что при категории user мы ищем по имени пользователя, а при repo ищем по названию репозитория.
Как это реализовать на react typescript?

Делать соответствующий запрос в зависимости от выбранной категории. Выбран user - шлем на один эндпоинт, выбран repo - на другой.

Еще так же по нажатию где то отслеживать(сохранять), какой экран демонстрировать пользователю
